# How to call Go lib from Dart using FFI

Tags: go, dart

I need to write a function in `GO`, compile it as a shared library, and then call it from `Dart`. For example, to return a key as in the code below:

```golang
package main

func getKey() string {
    theKey := "123-456-789"
    return theKey
}

func main() {}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is:

**Part One** the GO side:

1. We need to make the function exportable, so the name should be capitalized and become `GetKey()`
2. We need to use `cgo` so that we can create shared library, `cgo` means we need to:

2.1. Use `import "C"`

2.2. Use comment with the function as `//export GetKey`

2.3. Use `C.type` interface, in this example to instead of `string` use `C.char` and `C.CString` and as working with pointer is the preferable way, use `*C.char`

So, the `Go` function in the question, should be re-written as:

```golang
// filename: lib.go
package main

import "C"

//export GetKey
func GetKey() *C.char {
    theKey := "123-456-789"
    return C.CString(theKey)
}

func main() {}
```

3. Compile the above and create the shared library as:

```sh
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o lib.a lib.go
```

**Part Two** the Dart side:

1. Create the `pubspec.yaml` and add to its dependencies the `ffi: ^0.1.3`, so it be as:

```yaml
name: dart_app
description: A new Dart application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  ffi: ^0.1.3
```

2. Copy the generated files from GO which are `lib.a` and `lib.h` to the dart projetc folder
3. Create dart file to handle the FFI, where you need to:
   3.1. Import the `ffi` and the `utf8`

3.2. Define the FFI funtion signature as `typedef get_key_func = ffi.Pointer<Utf8> Function();`

3.3. Define the Dart funtion signature as `typedef GetKey = ffi.Pointer<Utf8> Function();`

3.4. Load the shared library as `final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open('lib.a');`

3.5. Map FFI and Dart function signatures as `final GetKey getKey dylib.lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<get_key_func>>('GetKey').asFunction();`

3.6. Define a function todo the execution, and inside this function do the following:

3.6.1. Invoke the Dart function and assign the output to a variabe as `var addressOf = getKey();`

3.6.2. Decode the result, which is the address of the pointer, and get the string from it, as: `print(addressOf.ref.toString());`

So, the Dart code will become:

```dart
//file name fficheck.dart
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi; // For FFI
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart';

typedef get_key_func = ffi.Pointer<Utf8> Function(); // FFI fn signature
typedef GetKey = ffi.Pointer<Utf8> Function(); // Dart fn signature
final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open('lib.a');

final GetKey getKey =
    dylib.lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<get_key_func>>('GetKey').asFunction();

void testffi() {
  print("Hi from dart");
  var addressOf = getKey();
  print(addressOf.ref.toString());
}
```

4. Create the main Dart file, and import the file that is handling the FFI, and call the required function, as:

```dart
// file name lib.dart
import 'fficheck.dart';

main() {
  print("Hello, World!");
  testffi();
}
```

5. Execute the dart file as `dart main.dart`

[image]

Quick note, not to go far from the scope of the question, if you return a string, then the return value from this function *must* be explicitly freed in the C code if if you call it from `C` code, but as you call it from garbage collector environment, Java/Kotlin you do not want to worry about it.

If freeing the allocated buffer isn't convenient, its common to fill a buffer provided by the caller:

```
func GetKey(buff *C.char, n int) int
```

If you can allocate the memory but don't want to handle C strings, you can insert the buffer into a pointer and return the size.

```
func GetKey(buff **C.char) int
```

Comment: Other than main() method in other widgets this getKey() is giving the below error any suggestions ? :Failed to load dynamic library 'lib/c_lib/lib.a': dlopen failed: library "lib/c_lib/lib.a" not found

Comment: What if the go lib returns an object, e.g. a network connection, rather than primitives like String or Int, how to work with the returned object?